# What is the meaning Sahih al bukhari hadith no 461?

Tags: sunnah, sahih-bukhari

In this hadith:

> "The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Last night a big demon (afreet) from the Jinns came to me and wanted to interrupt my prayers (or said something similar) but Allah enabled me to overpower him. I wanted to fasten him to one of the pillars of the mosque so that all of you could See him in the morning but I remembered the statement of my brother Solomon (as stated in Quran): My Lord! Forgive me and bestow on me a kingdom such as shall not belong to anybody after me (38.35)." The sub narrator Rauh said, "He (the demon) was dismissed humiliated." ([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:461))

Why did Prophet Muhammad (saw) quote that particular verse in this incident? And do we know why and how the demon was humiliated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. please provide the Hadith as the numbering differs in different compilations

Comment: We have already mentioned that the author's didn't numerate their books and therefore the numbers you refer to depend on modern editions and are not a reliable source of reference. It is therefore essential to quote the Hadith you are referring too the number is of no help. A hadith is referred to by it's matn (the content) and sanad (narrator chain) ... at least the source of the person on whom's authority it was narrated should be known. With the given information it is hard to find or locate the hadith you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (SAW) overpowered a Jinn, but decided not to tie him up to a pillar due to the dua of Sulaiman (AS) in 38:35.

Sulaiman (AS) was given command over the Jinn by Allah.

> And (we gave him) [also] the devils [of jinn] - every builder and diver
>
> And others bound together in shackles. (38:37-38)

He made the following dua:

> He said, "My Lord, forgive me and grant me a kingdom such as will not belong to anyone after me. Indeed, You are the Bestower." (38:35)

So, the Prophet (SAW) out of respect of this wish of his that no one else have a kingdom like his (and the kingdom Allah gave to him was of being able to control the Jinn among other things), decided not to tie up the Jinn himself.

The sub-narrator says: "He (the Prophet) dismissed him (the Jinn) humiliated." There is no special kind of humiliation meant here. Just how you would say someone was humiliated after they were overpowered.

Comment: I don't know how you guess the hadith, but still except of you and maybe OP none knows what you are talking about!

Comment: @Medi1Saif I guess so. I edited in the hadith for op.